# How to mobile-friendly menubar in vaadin 8?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

i saw on the vaadin demo website on the sampler a menubar which gets an icon at the end of it when its getting smaller. But there is no sourcecode which shows me how to do this. Does anyone know how they made it?

https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/interaction/menu-bar

Actually u can drag the arrows on the right down corner to make the space bigger or smaller. At the end of the menubar u can see a "play-icon" which gets the hidden menuitems.

but how?

Answer (score 0):

That’s a built-in feature of the MenuBar component. You need to set an explicit width for the component, for example `setWidth("100%")`. You can see it in the example source (click the (i) icon in the top right corner and open “Source” tab).